# iOS8 background standard-location updates after termination

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, cllocationmanager

I'm wondering if, in iOS8 *with all possible background-modes turned on*, the app will be woken up after termination to deliver location updates using the `standard-location updates` monitoring?

I've read all possible documentations, but I find it quite confusing because it at one point says the device will wake up the app, and at another point is says the device will not wake up the app when using `standard-location updates`.

My app needs continuous location updates with a movement-threshold of about 150 meters (max), and therefore the `standard-location-monitoring` seems appropriate. It also needs to keep getting these updates even if the app is terminated by the system, as it is crucial to the user.

I've come to understand that if using the `significant change location monitoring` the app **will be** woken up upon delivery of new data, but I'm still confused about the `standard location monitoring` when having requested `Always authorization` and having the `background updates` for location turned on.

Have anyone tested this, or know what happens? And if the app is not woken up after being terminated by the system, how can I solve that problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard location is something **your app** does. Thus your app needs to be running. It can operate in the foreground or you can even run in the background. But if your app is not running, it's not running; there is nothing to track.

Significant location monitoring and region monitoring, on the other hand, are done for you **by the system**, so it runs even if your app is not running, and you are woken up or launched to receive updates.

Comment: Even if I have turned on `App registers for location updates` and `Always Authorization`? 

And to follow up on that, when and what are the odds of, my application transitioning from `suspended` to `terminated`?

Comment: What I have said, I have said. This is reality - you need to face it.

Comment: "when and what are the odds of, my application transitioning from suspended to terminated?" System or user can terminate your suspended app without notice at any time. You must assume that backgrounding could mean termination.

Comment: For example when navigating with Google Maps, I still get notifications even though I have backgrounded the application and I might be using others - it seems as though Google Maps is also heavily reliant of standard-location updates in the background, but I've never once experienced it being terminated. 

So what are they doing differently? Are they just hoping the app never gets terminated?

Comment: How do you know they are _only_ doing standard-location updates? Maybe they are doing significant location monitoring or region monitoring _too_ - so they get woken up / relaunched by that, and now they can continue doing standard-location updates in the background.

Comment: However, it seems to me that you are just piling question upon question (leeching) in these comments. I believe I have answered the original question - what _you_ are able to do. This is the framework. This is what there is. It is your universe. You must accommodate your desires and technique to fit it.

Comment: That second answer was what I was looking for - "what are they doing differently?". Yes I asked more questions in the comments, but I felt it was better than writing an entirely new question on something that small - and I was already talking to a guy who seemed to know a lot about this stuff, so why not ask him?

I appreciate your answers, but I cannot say I appreciate your attitude. However, that's a totally different subject. Thanks.